# How to initialize context in fragment on Android kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-context

In my application i want show message when `fragment` has show.
I used `viewPager` and `BottomNavBar` for show **4 `fragments`**!
I want when click on `BottomNavBar` items show `fragment` and i want when **visibility** `fragment` **show message**.
I write below codes :

```
class HomeRegisteredFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var toolbarTile: TextView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_registered, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Initialize
        activity?.let {
            toolbarTile = it.findViewById(R.id.homePage_toolbarTitle)
        }
        //Set title
        toolbarTile.text = resources.getString(R.string.registered)
        context?.let { ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.blue_active) }?.let {
            toolbarTile.setTextColor(it)
        }
    }

    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            Log.e("showFragLog", "Show")
            context?.let { Toast.makeText(it, "Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        }
    }
}
```

In my above codes, when click on my `BottomNavBar` for show `fragment`, show me Log message but not show **Toast** message.
When click on another `BottomNavBar` items and again click on previous `BottomNavBar` item, then show **Toast** message.

I think in first time **not initialize** `context` in `setUserVisibleHint` method.

How can i initialize `context` for show **Toast** in every time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I changed your codes with below codes :

```
class HomeRegisteredFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var toolbarTile: TextView
    lateinit var handler: Handler

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_registered, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Initialize
        activity?.let {
            toolbarTile = it.findViewById(R.id.homePage_toolbarTitle)
        }
    }

    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            //Initialize
            handler = Handler()
            //Set delay
            handler.postDelayed({
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Show",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }, 10)
        }
    }
}
```

First you should use **`requireContext()`** instead of **`context()`** for avoid from memory leak.
For show Toast for every time, you can initialize handler in `setUserVisibleHint` , then after some delay run your code!

I hope help you

Comment: This code helped in that I was able to see that I needed to put my code in the on created

Comment: @TonyMerritt, you can use `onCreateView` method

Answer (score 7):

Storing context in a variable is a horrible practive and most of the times leads to memory leaks, use **requireContext()** this method was introduced in Support Library 27.1.0. Nowdays most likely you will have a newer version or even using **androidx** so there is no excuse for storing a context

Comment: by using requireContext() some time it throws error Fragment  not attached to a context.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for application context to show the toast message, try the below way and see if it works. Also, initialize it onCreate method so you have the activity context at that point.

```
val appContext = context!!.applicationContext
```

Answer (score 0):

O have a similar trouble here. I have one Activity with multiple Fragments, and I need a ListView to show some employes.
But when I call the Adapter class, I don't know how to pass the context variable:

```
binding.listviewCoordenacoes.isClickable = true
    binding.listviewCoordenacoes.adapter = CoordenadorAdapter(requireContext().applicationContext as Activity, arrayListCoordenador)
    binding.listviewCoordenacoes.setOnClickListener{}
```

In the examples in general, it works in Activities. If not possible, I will create an Activity and put it in that.